# Angular App Displays Firebase SDK Error in console in safari browser and displays white screen

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, safari, firebase-cloud-messaging

Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQyjs.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Cloud Messaging is currently not supported on Safari.  You can see the compatibility matrix for various Firebase products, including FCM [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/environments_js-sdk#browsers).  As of right now, Safari is marked unsupported.

Since you haven't shown any code, there is no specific advice I can give.  But it seems to me that you should be checking the result of some promise from its API to see if it was rejected.

You can read more [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1260).